# Stuck with a SUM in a SUM

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I'm stuck on this query sql. I've to do a SUM of values with a SUM of a value to get a Total. Some one can help me with this one ?

Here the beast :

```
Select 
    K.Id,
    K.Price1,
    K.Price2,
    SUM(H.Price3) as "Idontwork",
    K.Price4,
    K.Price5,
    K.Price6, 
    SUM(K.Price1,K.Price2,H.Idontwork) as FirstTotal,
    SUM(K.Price4,K.Price5,K.Price6) as SecondTotal,
    SUM(K.Price1,K.Price2,H.Idontwork)-SUM(K.Price4,K.Price5,K.Price6) as FinalTotal,
FROM TABLE1 K, TABLE2 H
WHERE K.ID=H.ID
GROUP BY 
    K.Id,K.Price1,K.Price2,K.Price4,K.Price5,K.Price6;
```

How can I use a SUM in a SUM? Is it possible?
I think the FinalTotal is not the best way to have itn do you have some advice ?

Thank in advance,

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do... do you meant just `SUM(K.Price1 + K.Price2 + H.Idontwork) as FirstTotal` etc.? `SUM()` is an aggregate function, and you seem to want simple addition within that, not another level of aggregates; what would you be grouping by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're grouping by the columns in table K I believe it's something like this

```
Select K.Id,
    K.Price1,
    K.Price2,
    SUM(H.Price3) as "Idontwork",
    K.Price4,
    K.Price5,
    K.Price6, 
    K.Price1+K.Price2+SUM(H.Price3) as FirstTotal,
    (K.Price4+K.Price5+K.Price6) as SecondTotal,
    (K.Price1+K.Price2)+SUM(H.Price3)-(K.Price4+K.Price5+K.Price6) as FinalTotal,
FROM TABLE1 K, TABLE2 H
WHERE K.ID=H.ID
GROUP BY K.Id,K.Price1,K.Price2,K.Price4,K.Price5,K.Price6;
```

Comment: Thx dude, that's work. I don't know why I wanted to do SUM of SUM since it's a sinple addition.